# ngmodel cannot hold address in a textbox if use with google address autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

I am using

```
  <input id="address" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" ng-model="vm.listingModal.streetAddress"
                    gm-places-autocomplete>
```

then address which come from the database not reflect in the filed but if I remove gm-places-autocomplete then it show the address from the database but stop showing google complete address.

Can someone help me to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you forgotten the options for gm-places directive?

Comment: I had checked all the options but nothing works